# On Load Server Posting Occurring Before Location Services Locates User

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server, location-services

Does location services run in the background?  I noticed that when I read the location from location manager into a global variable a post to parse-server it doesn't reflect the location data after insert.  I suspect that this is because the post code is running before the location manager function sets variables because it runs in the background.

Is there a way to start a location manager in view did load, but make sure that View did load waits until location services has finished its first update?

```
// VIEW DID LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        var secondsFromGMT: Int { return TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()
        // -----------------------
        // ? Wait for LOCATION SERVICES?? if placeIsSet {}
        // -----------------------
        let post = PFObject(className: "BlipPost")
        // need struct2Parse() function
        post["user_id"] = curBlip.user_id
        post["blip_msg"] = curBlip.blip_note
        post["blip_date"] = curBlip.blip_dt
        post["TZOffset_seconds"] = curBlip.blip_tz_secs
        post["blip_address"] = curBlip.blip_addr
        post["latitude"] = curBlip.blip_lat
        post["longitude"] = curBlip.blip_lon
        post["IsPublic"] = curBlip.isPublic
        print("location set about to post= \(locationSet)")
        post.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if success {
                print("location set success= \(self.locationSet)")
                print("Blip instantiated")
                curBlip.blip_id = post.objectId!
                // Should we add the new blip now or wait on "Save"
            } else {
                print("\(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            }
        }



// LOCATION MANAGER
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let addrDelim = " "
    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    currLocation = userLocation
    let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    location.lat = latitude
    location.lon = longitude
    location.strLatitude = String(format: "%.8f", latitude)
    location.strLongitude = String(format: "%.8f", longitude)
    location.strCourse = String(userLocation.course)
    location.strSpeed = String(userLocation.speed)
    location.strAltitude = String(userLocation.altitude)
    location.strLatLon = location.strLatitude + ", " + location.strLongitude
    locationSet = true

    // Reverse Geo Code for addr
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                var address = ""
                if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                    address += placemark.subThoroughfare! + " "
                    self.location.subThoroughfare = placemark.subThoroughfare!
                }
                if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
                    address += placemark.thoroughfare! + addrDelim
                    self.location.thoroughfare = placemark.thoroughfare!
                }
                if placemark.subLocality != nil {
                    address += placemark.subLocality! + addrDelim
                    self.location.subLocality = placemark.subLocality!
                }
                if placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                    address += placemark.subAdministrativeArea! + addrDelim
                    self.location.subAdministrativeArea = placemark.subAdministrativeArea!
                }
                if placemark.postalCode != nil {
                    address += placemark.postalCode! + addrDelim
                    self.location.postalCode = placemark.postalCode!
                }
                if placemark.country != nil {
                    address += placemark.country! + addrDelim
                    self.location.country = placemark.country!
                }
                self.location.strAddress = address
                print("location set in Manager= \(self.locationSet)")
                print(self.location.strAddress)
            }
        }
    }
    // Stop updating location to save battery
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: Why not just move the code that requires a location into the didUpdateLocation delegate method?

Comment: That is the work around I am working on right now, but I had to think it was my inexperience and there was a "right way" to do this.  I figured it wasn't ideal because I would have to put a bool that prevents it from happening every time the location updates after the initial location is set.

Comment: But you call stopUpdatingLocation once you get the first location, isn't that enough?